# Is it possible to take snapshot and restore with elasticsearch-curator without loosing the updates in the destination index?

Tags: elasticsearch-curator

I am able to run the curator to take the snapshot from the source index and restore the same snapshot in the destination index.
But all the updations that I did on the destination index are lost after the next snapshot and restore action.

Is it possible to specify not to overwrite the updations of the destination index?

**source index:** test_index

**destination index:** dest_test_index

**snapshot-action.yml file**

```
actions:
  1:
    action: snapshot
    description: Snapshot selected indices to 'repository' with the snapshot name or name pattern in 'name'.  Use all other options as assigned
    options:
      repository: esbackup
      name:
      wait_for_completion: True
      max_wait: 3600
      wait_interval: 10
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: regex
      value: '^(test_index)$'
      exclude:
```

**restore-action.yml file**

```
actions:
  1:
    action: create_index
    description: "Create the temporary index with dest_index_v2 name"
    options:
      name: dest_index_v2
  2:
    action: close
    description: >-
      Close index dest_indiex_v2.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      skip_flush: False
      delete_aliases: False
      ignore_sync_failures: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: dest_index_v2
  3:
    action: restore
    description: >-
      Restore test_index from the most recent snapshot in temp index dest_index_v2.
    options:
      repository: esbackup
      # If name is blank, the most recent snapshot by age will be selected
      name:
      # If indices is blank, all indices in the snapshot will be restored
      indices: ['test_index']
      rename_pattern: test_index
      rename_replacement: dest_index_v2
      wait_for_completion: True
      max_wait: 3600
      wait_interval: 10
    filters:
    - filtertype: none
  4:
    action: open
    description: >-
      Open index pattern dest_index_v2.
    options:
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: dest_index_v2
      exclude:
  5:
    description: "Reindex dest_index_v2 into dest_test_index"
    action: reindex
    options:
      wait_interval: 9
      max_wait: -1
      request_body:
        source:
          index: dest_index_v2
        dest:
          index: dest_test_index
    filters:
    - filtertype: none
  6:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete index dest_index_v2. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
      actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: dest_index_v2
```

Comment: > Is it possible to specify not to overwrite the updations of the destination index?

I'm trying to follow what you're doing here. You're restoring an older version of the index from a snapshot, and you don't want it to overwrite newer changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some elasticsearch setting which will merge in updated destination index with the source index(which you are restoring from snapshot), then the short answer is **NO**.

You can write custom code to perform following operation to make sure destination index update is not lost.

1. Restore source index(`test_index`) to a temporary index in the cluster
   , lets call this index as `temp_index`
2. Retrieve documents from `temp_index`  and insert in destination index (`dest_test_index`) with `op_type=create`
   Operation type `create` will make sure that the index operation will fail if a document by that id already exists in the index.
   You can refer to documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/docs-index_.html#operation-type)

Hope this solves your purpose.

Comment: Yes, this. You cannot merge a snapshot with an index because snapshots don't operate at the document level, but rather at the segment level. The above workaround provides a way to accomplish the desired result.